# is it possible to use Auto_publish?

Tags: facebook, fbjs, facebook-iframe, facebook-javascript-sdk

is it possible to use Auto_publish in Iframe Canvas 
I think all the facebook applications developer used the fbjs > Facebook.streamPublish to auto publish
if using Auto_publish , how can we use it?

Comment: Thanks I Got the solution from the official documentation too  i found this code will help `If you have an authenticated user with the publish_stream permission, and want to publish a new story to their feed:

var body = 'Reading Connect JS documentation';
FB.api('/me/feed', 'post', { message: body }, function(response) {
  if (!response || response.error) {
    alert('Error occured');
  } else {
    alert('Post ID: ' + response.id);
  }
});
`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the FB javascript sdk in iframe application. See this [link](http://www.takwing.idv.hk/tech/fb_dev/jssdk/learning_jssdk_12.html) for more details..

(under Publishing a Post using the new JavaScript SDK)